# Laravel : Download Button not working properly

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make user download file from the page. But, whenever I click on the download button, this error appears:

> The requested resource /download was not found on this server.

Here's my code.

**view:**

```
<a href="/download/file_name" class="btn btn-large pull-right"><i class="icon-download-alt"> </i> Download Brochure </a>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function getDownload($file_name) {
$file_path = public_path('files/'.$file_name);
return response()->download($file_path);}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/download/{file}', 'DownloadFileController@getDownload');
```

and it shows : [image]

**The error showing is**::

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/download Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I just don't get it, how to fix this?

**and shows**

> Undefined variable: file_name (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Land_Map\resources\views\pages\upload.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Land_Map\resources\views\pages\upload.blade.php)

**when I use:**

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('/download/'.$file_name) }}" class="btn btn-large pull-right"><i class="icon-download-alt"> </i> Download Brochure </a>
```

**But, works fine with**

```
<a href="/download/php_tutorial.pdf" class="btn btn-large pull-right"><i class="icon-download-alt"> </i> Download Brochure </a>
```

But, I want the user to select from several files in the download folder. But, don't know how to do it. Tried several ways, but didn't work.

I also tried:

```
<a href="{{route('upload')}}" class="btn btn-large pull-right"><i class="icon-download-alt"> </i> Download Brochure </a>
```

I was actually trying to show the files being uploaded, but didn't work.

But, it shows:

> Route [upload] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Land_Map\resources\views\pages\upload.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Land_Map\resources\views\pages\upload.blade.php)

But, Routes :

```
Route::get('/upload', 'FormUploadController@upload');

Route::post('upload', 'UploadController@upload');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass filename:

```
<a href="/download/Guide.pdf" ....>Download Brochure</a>
```

If you do not pass filename, Laravel will look for this route:

```
Route::get('/download', 'DownloadFileController@getDownload');
```

Comment: Thank you, I did it, also edited the question. but now it shows: Not Found
The requested resource /download was not found on this server.

Comment: It's another kind of error, I guess something's wrong with web server configuration.

Comment: web server configuration, alright. I'll see that. But, please can you specify a little about what might be wrong?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) :: This is the error

Answer (score 1):

I think your code need to update like:

**For controller**

```
public function getDownload($file_name) {
    $file_path = public_path().'/files/'.$file_name;
    return response()->download($file_path);
}
```

**For blade file:**

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('/download/'.$filename) }}"class="btn btn-large pull-right"><i class="icon-download-alt"> </i> Download Brochure </a>
```

**UPDATE**
Here, make sure that `$filename` should be passed from your controller view like given into [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#passing-data-to-views).
Hope this work for you!

Comment: Alright, I tried that. But it shows :: Undefined variable: filename (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Land_Map\resources\views\pages\upload.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Land_Map\resources\views\pages\upload.blade.php)

Comment: @Rock See my *UPDATE*

Comment: I saw your update, Tried several ways. But didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

In href you have to add the filename href="/download/file_name"